# App not working in OS 4.4.x to 5.x but working in 7.0.0 or higher

Tags: android

I am working android studio 3.2.1 and my app running android 7.0.0 or higher. But when i run it in lower version emulator or device like 4.4.4 or 5.1.1 it crash due to this following error and say unable to start activity

```
    10-24 07:26:22.936 1630-1630/com.gcc.drt_driver E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.gcc.drt_driver, PID: 1630
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gcc.drt_driver/com.gcc.drt_driver.activities.Login}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at com.gcc.drt_driver.activities.Login.onCreate(Login.java:41)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at com.gcc.drt_driver.activities.Login.onCreate(Login.java:41) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f07005e a=-1 r=0x7f07005e}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2068)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3554)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:470)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:176)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:172)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at com.gcc.drt_driver.activities.Login.onCreate(Login.java:41) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
10-24 07:26:23.856 804-804/com.android.launcher E/EGL_emulation: tid 804: eglSurfaceAttrib(1210): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
10-24 07:26:24.004 610-755/system_process I/ActivityManager: Killing 1296:com.android.exchange/u0a30 (adj 15): empty #17
10-24 07:26:31.380 610-625/system_process E/WindowManager: Starting window AppWindowToken{529afe08 token=Token{529640c0 ActivityRecord{52860098 u0 com.gcc.drt_driver/.activities.Login t2}}} timed out
```

my gradle file like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gcc.drt_driver"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"


    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.all {
                    outputFileName = "drt_driver-v${variant.versionName}.apk"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
    }
}

dependencies {


    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.+'

    //implementation 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.30.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.20'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'

    implementation 'com.joooonho:selectableroundedimageview:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.4'
    releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.4'


    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'

    implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$BUTTERKNIFE_VERSION"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    kapt "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$BUTTERKNIFE_VERSION"

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'


}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

and manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gcc.drt_driver">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".activities.Login">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.Dashboard"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_dashboard"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBKmFxyacVaTHpBnab1iR0_y_GN_LYjGNc" />

        <activity android:name=".activities.TripList" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.TripHistory" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.PassengerList"></activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

and also the login.xml file like this

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <!--<ImageView-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/logo_image"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="120dp"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="120dp"-->
    <!--android:src="@drawable/login_logo"-->
    <!--android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"-->
    <!--android:layout_marginTop="50dp"-->

    <!--/>-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="230dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:orientation="vertical">



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_id"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorLoginTxt"
            android:ems="12"
            android:text="LOGIN" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/usernameWrapper"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextLoginUser"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_below="@+id/customView"
                android:ems="12"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:hint="@string/user_name_hint"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/passwordWapper"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextLoginPassword"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editTextLoginUser"
                android:ems="12"
                android:hint="@string/user_password_hint"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSignIn"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editTextLoginPassword"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="performLogin"
            android:text="@string/login_btn"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/regView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp">

            <!--<TextView-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/text_reg"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:layout_marginTop="0dp"-->
                <!--android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"-->
                <!--android:layout_gravity="center"-->
                <!--android:textSize="18sp"-->
                <!--android:onClick="performReg"-->
                <!--android:textColor="@color/colorRegTxt"-->
                <!--android:text="@string/reg_btn" />-->
            <!--<TextView-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/text_forgetPass"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:layout_marginTop="0dp"-->
                <!--android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"-->
                <!--android:layout_gravity="center"-->
                <!--android:textSize="18sp"-->
                <!--android:onClick="forgetPassword"-->
                <!--android:textColor="@color/colorRegTxt"-->
                <!--android:text="@string/forget_pass_btn" />-->

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!--<ImageView-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/loadSyncDataIv"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="55dp"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="55dp"-->
    <!--android:layout_margin="15dp"-->
    <!--android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"-->
    <!--android:clickable="true"-->
    <!--android:src="@drawable/load"-->
    <!--android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

anybody have solution ?

my border.xml is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace as text.

Comment: show the stacktrace **as text**

Comment: you have some problem with a drawable. Probably `@drawable/border`. Show it's source

Comment: share your border.xml

Comment: Share your border drawable. You are likely using elements in there that are not supported. Are you using vectors? if so you need to use compatSrc instead for setting images and can have more issues on pre lollipop. So need to see what you are using for drawables

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>

Comment: The problem is in border.xml file but not find out

Comment: Edit with border.xml

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your drawable resource in drawable-v21.

Comment: Are you using vector drawable ?